# R shiny tooltips when a user put his cursor on a buble(gene)

Tags: r, shiny

Hello I have built this R shiny app using kegg packages and a xml file from the website. The app runs but i would like to add toolips when the user puts his cursor on an observation (gene presented in a buble). If you see in the code below I have created a dataframe named gene_info_df which has the information i want to show at the "description" variable. Could you please help me with that if you have any idea? thank you

```
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.15")
BiocManager::install("KEGGgraph")
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("KEGGREST")
BiocManager::install("EnrichmentBrowser")
library("KEGGREST")
library("EnrichmentBrowser")

library(KEGGgraph)
library(shiny)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Pathway testing"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "geneInput",
        label = "Genes",
        choices = c("hsa05212"),
      ),
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = "searchme", 
        label = "Search Bar",
        multiple = FALSE,
        choices = c("Search Bar" = "", paste0(LETTERS,sample(LETTERS, 26))),
        options = list(
          create = FALSE,
          placeholder = "Search Me",
          maxItems = '1',
          onDropdownOpen = I("function($dropdown) {if (!this.lastQuery.length) {this.close(); this.settings.openOnFocus = false;}}"),
          onType = I("function (str) {if (str === \"\") {this.close();}}")
        ))
    ),
    
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId="genePlot", width = 1400, height=900)
    )
  )
)
gene_info <- keggGet("hsa05212")
## a function to parse the data
parseIt <- function(x) {
  nr <- length(x$GENE)
  GeneID <- x$GENE[seq(1, nr, 2)]
  d.f <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(x$GENE[seq(2, nr, 2)], "; "))
  colnames(d.f) <- c("SYMBOL","DESCRIPTION")
  data.frame(GeneID, d.f)
}
gene_info_df <- parseIt(gene_info[[1]])
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$genePlot <- renderPlot({
    # Retreive KEGG data
    mapkKGML <- system.file(sprintf("extdata/%s.xml", input$geneInput),package="KEGGgraph")
    wntKGML <- system.file(sprintf("extdata/%s.xml",input$geneInput), package="KEGGgraph")
    
    #Format KEGG data into useable format
    mapkG <- parseKGML2Graph(mapkKGML,expandGenes=TRUE)
    mapkGall <- parseKGML2Graph(mapkKGML,genesOnly=FALSE)

    mapkGsub <- subGraphByNodeType(mapkGall, "compound")

    wntG <- parseKGML2Graph(wntKGML, genesOnly=TRUE)
    graphs <- list(mapk=mapkGsub, wnt=wntG)
    merged <- mergeGraphs(graphs)
    #Defining functions for ploting the node graph
    makeAttr <- function(graph, default, valNodeList) {
      tmp <- nodes(graph)
      x <- rep(default, length(tmp)); names(x) <- tmp
      
      if(!missing(valNodeList)) {
        stopifnot(is.list(valNodeList))
        allnodes <- unlist(valNodeList)
        stopifnot(all(allnodes %in% tmp))
        for(i in seq(valNodeList)) {
          x[valNodeList[[i]]] <- names(valNodeList)[i]
        }
      }
      return(x)
    }
    
    # Block of code responsible for setting the attributes of the plot
    outs <- sapply(edges(merged), length) > 0
    ins <- sapply(inEdges(merged), length) > 0
    ios <- outs | ins
    ## translate the KEGG IDs into Gene Symbol
    if(require(org.Hs.eg.db)) {
      
      ioGeneID <- translateKEGGID2GeneID(names(ios))
      
      tmp <- c()
      
      for (i in ioGeneID) {
        if (is.na(mget(sprintf("%s",i),  org.Hs.egSYMBOL, ifnotfound = NA))) {
          tmp <- append(tmp,sprintf("%s",i))
        }
        else {
          tmp <- append(tmp,mget(sprintf("%s",i),  org.Hs.egSYMBOL))
        }
      }
      nodesNames <- sapply(tmp, "[[",1)
    } else {
      nodesNames <- names(ios)
    }
    names(nodesNames) <- names(ios)
    
    nAttrs <- list();
    nAttrs$fillcolor <- makeAttr(merged, "lightgrey", list(orange=names(ios)[ios]))
    nAttrs$label <- nodesNames
    plot(merged, "neato", nodeAttrs=nAttrs,
         attrs=list(node=list(fillcolor="lightgreen",
                              width="0.75", shape="ellipse"), 
                    edge=list(arrowsize="0.7")))
    
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It is not very likely you can do so with `renderPlot`. It gives you a png image that lacks interactivity. You chances are higher If you can manage to make your plot with `networkD3`, `DiagrammeR`, `plotly` or any package that uses `htmlwidgets` .

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if you have the time because i tried to use plotly but because i am facing issues because my data set is coming from xml file do you have any idea about the code?

Comment: I suggest you try with `networkD3`  or `DiagrammeR` first. Figuring out the algorithm of the network plot is a very task in `plotly`. The other two packages have embedded algorithms to calculate these networks. You just need the right format. Once you have an interactive plot, we can help you from there.